# how to add profile scope and email scopes in Google OAuth in C#(Windows form)

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, scope

How to add  profile scope and email scopes in Google OAuth, i am using the code given below.

```
        string tokenRequestURI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
        string tokenRequestBody = string.Format("code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&code_verifier={3}&client_secret={4}&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code",
            code,
            System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
            clientID,
            code_verifier,
            clientSecret
            );

        // sends the request
        HttpWebRequest tokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tokenRequestURI);
        tokenRequest.Method = "POST";
        tokenRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        tokenRequest.Accept = "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        byte[] _byteVersion = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenRequestBody);
        tokenRequest.ContentLength = _byteVersion.Length;
        Stream stream = tokenRequest.GetRequestStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(_byteVersion, 0, _byteVersion.Length);
        stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not sending any scopes in your tokenRequestBody have you tried adding them there?

```
string tokenRequestBody = string.Format("code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&code_verifier={3}&client_secret={4}&scope={5}&grant_type=authorization_code",
        code,
        System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
        clientID,
        code_verifier,
        clientSecret,
        "email profile"
        );
```

You should really look into use the Google .net client library rather than doing this all manually.

Comment: I have added this code. still didn't get email address. I have added scopes in google cloud platform. Can you check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217242/how-to-get-email-address-from-google-cloud-platform-api (added scopes in google cloud platform)